# Logon failure error when attempting UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been searching for solutions on this for a while now, but each thread a dead-end unfortunately.

I'm working on a C#/ASP.net web app that will only be used internally by our company. Anonymous access has been switched off both in IIS and my web.config file forcing IIS to use the windows authenticated user (Active Dir user).

My problem is that the following code works perfectly to get the required (or any) AD user:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

... other code ...

PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain", "someADuser", "someADuserpassword");
UserPrincipal winuser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "samaccountname");
```

"someADuser" used in the PrincipalContext above is the current logged in user through windows, thus authenticated and a valid AD user. Using the following code (with the exact same user still logged in) gives me a "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password" error:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain");
UserPrincipal winuser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "samaccountname");
```

It seems UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity doesn't use the logged in user's validated credentials for some reason if it's not specified in the PrincipalContext object - something I don't want to do.

Is it possible that the ctx aren't picking up the logged in Windows users for some reason, even if the necessary settings (i hope) is added to web.config :

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

And Anonymous access is completely disabled in IIS?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are trying to do this programmatically why not use impersonation? You can set to a specific AD user then? Is that what you are trying to do ?

Comment: @TheKingDave, I need to get more info from AD for the logged in user (account locked / enabled, guid etc.) as this app will be hosted on the server, accessed by many across the domain. Hope I understood your question and answered clearly? Thx for the response...

Comment: What is `ctx.UserName` after you create the PrincipalContext object?

Comment: Good question @jadarnel27, it's empty or "". I'm under the impression that if anonymous access is off everywhere, the context object will default to the logged in windows user, which it seems it's not.

Comment: Even adding ContextOptions.Negotiate to the PrincipalContext which states exactly what my previous comment suggests, doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

> It seems UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity doesn't use the logged in user's validated credentials for some reason if it's not specified in the PrincipalContext object - something I don't want to do.

UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity doesn't care about the user's credentials at all.  You're just performing a look up to see if the account exists.  The reason you're getting an error is because the default user credentials (i.e. the identity that your web application is running as) doesn't have access to the directory, so it can't perform the look up.  When you pass in the client's credentials to the PrincipalContext then the problem goes away because your client has a valid AD account with access to the directory.

You should investigate which identity is being used to run the application pool and make sure it has access to the directory.

Comment: I hear what you're saying @RogerN and maybe I'm just completely lost on how IIS really works (in my defence, first time i have to deal with AD and an issue like this), but I'm of the opinion that turning off anonymous access in IIS AND configuring the web.config file of the web-app to deny anonymous access, automatically falls on the user identity who initiates the "thread" call from the aspx page?

Comment: Oh and "Integrated Windows Authentication" is switched on in IIS as well

Comment: From the MS site (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345952.aspx): "If the username and password parameters are both null, the default credentials of the current principal are used". So in theory my code should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: For web applications there's a difference between the app's identity and the user's identity.  Inspect User.Identity.Name and System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.  I think you'll find they are different.  The believe the latter is what's being used when you create the PrincipalContext without specifying credentials.

Comment: You might be right... the current principal or UserPrincipal.Current is the built in ASP user for ASP.net web apps, which means if no user is specified it defaults to this. Is it even possible to let it default to the windows authenticated logged in user?

Comment: I found a solution (or workaround) to this thanks to @RogerN and @TheKingDave! Answer posted...

Answer (score 3):

Quite annoying as I though if anonymous access was turned off, the current principal would default to the user logged in to windows. It turns out it's not as indicated by @RogerN.

Using the following statement as mentioned by @TheKingDave, it basically impersonates the user logged in to windows and makes the current thread run on it's principal rather than the "ASP" (in my case) account.

Because all the users on our domain has query/read access to Active Directory, this shouldn't be a problem to get more detail on them, which is what I wanted in the first place.

The end code (was testing):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Impersonate();
ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName);
UserPrincipal winuser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "whicheveraccount");
```

Hope it helps some1 in future! thx! ;-)

Comment: It did not worked for me do you want to share more details about like how the app pool is set to?

Comment: Not sure if you came right @codebased but my application pool was asp.net 4 with a classic managed pipeline running under the network service identity. In my case only windows auth was enabled for the application running under the default website as an application. Hope it helps?

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of search/research to resolve the issue, but nothing worked, at last, all what I did was to add `@` to the servername, container, username & password like below:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, @"abc.net", @"OU=Customers,DC=abc,DC=net", ContextOptions.SimpleBind, @"abcnet\authuser", @"!$%MyPassword"));
```

And it worked. doh!

Comment: What type of variable is `app`?

Comment: Its `public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` in MVC `Startup` configuration class

Comment: Additionally values from `Properties.Settings.Default.DomainName` also worked without `@`

Comment: Oh, ok, good to know.  I was using this code in a WPF app so don't think it had this.

Comment: Also, "@" was needed above because you had `@"abcnet\authuser"`.  You have to either escape the slash with another slash, or use `@` to prevent having to, as you found out.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out how to pass the impersonated identity.  I had a situation where, as an admin, I wanted to unlock a user account automatically.  I had to get the user names into variables and pass them in to the function like this:

```
string accountname = @"domain\username";
string admin = "adminusername";
string domain = Environment.UserDomainName;
string password = "password";
string dc = "WIN2K8DC1";  // example host name of domain controller, could use IP

// This determines the domain automatically, no need to specify
// Use the constructor that takes the domain controller name or IP, 
// admin user name, and password
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, dc, admin, password); 

UserPrincipal winuser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, accountname)

if (winuser != null)
{
    WindowsImpersonationContext wic = Impersonation.doImpersonation(admin, domain, password); //class/function that does the logon of the user and returns the WIC
    if (wic != null)
    {
        winuser.UnlockAccount();
    }
}
```

Impersonation class functionality that can be used to return a WIC can be found on MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx